# how to import term by name in csv file in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

I need to import a CSV with 3-4 fields with taxonomy, but I need to insert taxonomy by name. Is it possible with the [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
> data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
> progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
> exporting in the following types:
>
> CSV
>
> Microsoft XLS
>
> Microsoft DOC
>
> Basic TXT
>
> XML.

Requirements

The batched export functionality of this module requires a MySQL database.
This module also requires version 2.7 or higher of views.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Taxonomy CSV import/export` module
[image]

Comment: I am getting General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE0 Cali...' for column 'message' at row 1 .. at the time importing csv using feed module.